# How to convert an SQL statement to an SQLite statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to convert this SELECT statement to an SQLite statement?

```
SELECT count(`listId`) AS countP, 
       DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'),
                             INTERVAL IF( MINUTE( timestamp )<30, 0, 1) HOUR), '%H:30') AS hourP
  FROM `polldata` 
 WHERE `gcId`=01
   AND `listId`=02
 GROUP BY hourP
 ORDER BY hourP
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: By using sqlite syntaxes... That's when you may refer to the sqlite manual.

Comment: you can start by stripping out all those backticks

Comment: Why do you think it won't work in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

You want to take an existing MySQL file and translate it into its SQL Lite equivalent.

There are two parts to this process:

1.Translate the DDL from one SQL database to another (DDL == "Data Definition Language")

2.Migrate data from one schema to another.

Every SQL vendor starts with ANSI SQL and adds in their own proprietary syntax. So you'll    have to create a SQL Lite schema (tables, columns, indexes, etc) from the MySQL definition.

The data migration process is called ETL ("Extract-Transform-Load"). You might have to massage some of that data from MySQL to get it into SQL Lite.

The best scenario would be to export your MySQL data into a .csv file, create the table in SQL Lite, then import the .csv file.

Refer here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a native timestamp type.
Assuming that timestamps are stored as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` strings, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT count(`listId`) AS countP,
       strftime('%H:30',
                timestamp,
                CASE WHEN substr(timestamp, 15, 2) < '30'
                     THEN '1 hours'
                     ELSE '0 hours'
                END) as hourP
  FROM `polldata` 
 WHERE `gcId`=01
   AND `listId`=02
 GROUP BY hourP
 ORDER BY hourP
 LIMIT 0, 30
```